# Prove $|(0, 1]| = |\mathbb{R}|$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I could find [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524154/prove-that-mathbbr-0-1) for $|(0,1)| = |\mathbb{R}|$, but could not find anything about $|(0, 1]| = |\mathbb{R}|$. I do not know how to prove this. The only way I can think of is showing that there is a bijection from $(0, 1] \rightarrow (0,1)$, then we will have $|(0, 1]| = |(0,1)| = |\mathbb{R}|$. However, I would like to prove this by using The Schroder-Bernstein theorem with $(0,1]$. What would be the key difference between $|(0,1)| = |\mathbb{R}|$ and $|(0, 1]| = |\mathbb{R}|$? I think there still should be the bijection from $(0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but I'm struggling with coming up with idea.

Comment: Are you trying to show $|(0,1]| = |(0,1)|$ with Schroder-Bernstein? Or are you trying to show $|(0,1]| = |\mathbb{R}|$ _directly_ with Schroder-Bernstein?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I'd like to prove in the latter way which is showing $|(0,1]| = |\mathbb{R}|$ directly with Schroder-Bernstein. Sorry for my messy post.

Comment: I'm forced to leave this as a comment, since it seems your question was closed. Sorry that's going to make it a bit harder to read. It's clear that the standard inclusion $\iota : (0,1] \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an injection. So it suffices to find an injection $f : \mathbb{R} \to (0,1]$.
But notice, say $f(x) = \frac{1}{2 + e^x}$ is a function $\mathbb{R} \to (0,1]$. 
Can you show it is an injection?
As a hint, you might want to write $f$ as the composite
1. $y = e^x$
2. $z = y + 2$
3. $f = 1/z$.
I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: That's easy then! Let $f: \mathbb R \to (0,1)$ be your bijection.  THen $f:\mathbb R\to (0,1]$ is injective (but not surjective).  And let $g:(0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be the identity function.  That is injective but not surjective.  SO via SB Th we know a bijection between $(0,1]$ and $\mathbb R$ must exist.  SB doesn't tell us *what* it is, but it tells us one *does* exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lemma: If $X$ is an infinite set and $a \not \in X$ then $|X \cup \{a\}| = |X|$.

SO if $|(0,1)| = |\mathbb R|$ then $|(0,1]|=|(0,1)\cup \{1\}| = |(0,1)| = |\mathbb R|$.

SO let's prove the lemma.

Let $a \not \in X$ and $X$ is not empty so there is an $x_1\in X$.  Let $\phi(a)= x_1$.

$X$ is infinite so $X_1= X\setminus \{x_1\}$ is infinite (why?) so there is an $x_2\in X_1$.  So let $\phi(x_1) = x_2$.

Via recursion induction we can define $X_{k} = X_{k-1} - \{x_{k-1}\}$ is infinite and and $x_{k} \in X_{k}$ as $\phi(x_{k-1}) = x_k$.

So we end up with an infinite countable set $\{a, x_1, x_2, .....\}$ with $\phi(a) = x_1$ and $\phi(x_k) = x_{k+1}$.  For all $w \in X \setminus \{a, x_1, x_2, .....\}$ we can just let $\phi(w) = w$.

That is a bijection.

.....

Or a practical example.  Let $\phi(1) = \frac 12$.  And $\phi (\frac 1{2^k}) = \frac 1{2^{k+1}}$.  Other wise let $\phi(w) = w$.

That is a bijection of $(0,1]\to (0,1)$.  Compose it with your bijection of $(0,1)\to \mathbb R$.

That is.... if $\chi: (0,1)\to \mathbb R$ then let $\phi(\frac 1{2^k}) =\chi (\frac 1{2^{k+1}})$.  and for all other $w$ let $\phi(w) = \chi(w)$.

===

Ah,  Shroeder Berstein!  That makes it *easy*!

Let $f:(0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be $f(x) =x$.  That's clearly injective. (but not onto)

And let $g:\mathbb R \to (0,1]$ be... well, whatever you did for $\mathbb R\to (0,1)$ extend it to $(0,1]$ and it will be injective but not unto....

We can use $\arctan: \mathbb R \to (-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)$ is bijective.

So $\frac {\arctan x +\frac \pi 2}{\pi}: \mathbb R \to (0,1)$ is bijective.

So $g(x) = \frac {\arctan x +\frac \pi 2}{\pi}$ so $g:\mathbb R \to (0,1]$ is *in*jective.  (It's not onto as there is no $x: g(x)=1$ but we don't *need* it to be onto.  Just injective.)

So as we have injective  $f:(0,1]\to \mathbb R$ and injective $g:\mathbb R\to (0,1]$ we know a bijection $\chi: (0,1]\to \mathbb R$ must exist.

Just what is that bijection?.... who the @#%\$ knows and who the @#%\$ cares?  We have the SB theorem so we don't *have* to care.  Citing theorems is free.  Thinking will cost you extra.

Comment: I didn't know that we don't need a bijection. This helps a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Well, you *do* need a bijection.  But SB Theorem says that you know one exists.   You don't have to know what it *is*; just that it exists.